# Group by without join on Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I need a query that returns me a foreign key and a count, something like this:

array(
    105 => '22',
    120 => '30'
)

If I try this:

```
    select i.client , count(i) as total 
    from \Invoice i 
    GROUP BY i.client
```

Got error:
Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

I guess that its because i.client is an asociation not a simple field.

The only way I've found is to make it work is with a join but I dont think its needed since I only want the FK

```
    select c.id , count(i) as total 
    from \Invoice i 
    join i.client c
    GROUP BY i.client
```

Is there any way to do this count without the join?

Answer (score 0):

If `client` is the id to another table, this works for me:

```
select i.client, count(i.id) as total from Invoice i group by i.client
```

Comment: client is an assotiation, you are proposing the same dql that gave me the error?

Comment: sorry, you're right but I tested that and did not give me one.

Comment: Try doing a select for the `id` of the association